# The word I heard for the smell of something dead is carne not sure I spelled it right

Tags: single-word-requests

Has anyone heard of the word "carne" when you smell something dead not sure of spelling

Answer (score 6):

[Carne](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/carne) simply means "meat" in Spanish, Italian, and several other Latin-descended languages; I don't think that's what you mean unless it was a grimly-humorous usage, like calling raw recruits "fresh meat".  In general, however, "carne" refers to intentionally-butchered meat, intended as food.

[Carrion](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/carrion) is dead, rotting meat such as roadkill, animals that died of disease, etc.  Vultures live almost exclusively on carrion; it does have a particular smell, but "carrion" is a noun, not an adjective.

A [charnel](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/charnel), or [charnel house](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/charnel%20house), is a building where bodies or bones are deposited - a sort of mortuary chapel or mausoleum.  The use of charnel houses predates modern embalming or sanitation, so there is an accompanying aroma that has entered the language: you can speak of a *charnel-house reek*.

> It had a **charnel-house reek** about it-gases formed in the chamber of death, no doubt, and dangerous to the living.

[("When Churchyards Yawn", N.W.Erickson, 2012)](https://books.google.com/books?id=TcXOAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA66&lpg=PA66&dq=charnel-house%20reek&source=bl&ots=nIGX1u6gwo&sig=krKc06Uuc3tpY_GM8iIpOxK4ujw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwia0LjHw8vdAhWKi1QKHdzyAaYQ6AEwCXoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=charnel-house%20reek&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answer, it sound to me as if you have just misheard something else.

"I smell [**carnage**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/carnage)."

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **1** : the flesh of slain animals or humans.